# Tracking annotations for a collection of books with a SQL Database

Tags: mysql, database-design

I like to create a database driven web application (PHP with mySQL) that displays the collected works (sources) of several ancient and medieval philosophers. The sources should be available in their original languages, mainly Ancient Greek, Latin, and Arabic. Users should be able to translate and comment any content of sources.

Author's `i` collected works are stored in  `scrAuthori`:

```
 PK
|scrAuthoriId|booktitle|page|line|position|word
|1           |bookA    |1   |1   |1       |word1
|2           |bookA    |1   |1   |2       |word2
...
|342         |bookB    |234 |3   |11      |word3453
```

Author’s `i` collected works  have different kinds of content that are of interest: words, expressions covering more then two words, a sentence, sentences, a paragraph, paragraphs, etc. Users are able to define what content is of interest (i.e. BookA, page 1, line 3 to  BookA, page 3, line 5). The will translate the content and add comments to it.

Contents are defined in `authoriContents`:

```
 PK                FK1          FK2
|authoriContentsId|scrAuthoriId1|scrAuthoriId2|
|1                |1            |100
|231              |234          |1029
```

Translation in `translationsAuthori`:

```
 PK                    FK
|translationAuthorIId|authorIContentsId|translation|
|1                   |3                |uvw
|2                   |3                |xyz
|2                   |45               |abc
```

The relation between comments and content has to be many-to-many: A user’s comment pertains to two or more contents and content could have more than one comment.

`authorIContents_author1Comments`:

```
 FK                FK
|authoriContentsId|authoriCommentsId
|1                |3        
|4                |3        
|231              |45
```

`authoriComments`:

```
 PK                FK
|authoriCommentsId |comment
|3                 |comment on content 1 and 4
|45                |comment on content 231
```

Since this is my first database application I’am not sure if the solution feasible. Is it a bad decision in light of performance to store the collected works word by word? Each `scrAuthori`, `i = 1, 2, ... 10` will have up to one million rows. Once established the rows of `scrAuthori` will not change. Is there any better approach to the problem of tracking annotations to various kind of content?

Comment: This seems like a step too far up the normalisation ladder. I would opt for full text indexes instead.

Comment: To the best of my limited knowledge a full text index' intend is to speed up full text searches. Although the database will also serve searches it's main purpose is to track translations and comments of classical sources' content. In this sense the database mimics a critical apparatus (like this [one](http://www.fluxus-virus.com/en/what-critical.html). In addition to this the database will establish links between comments (not mapped in my example) and serve as a dictionary for philosophical concepts. But I'am afraid that the word by word approach (scrAuthori) will lead to performance issues.

Comment: Have you thought of just stopping at the line level and capturing start position and end position of the comments?  That would allow the comment to go from an arbitrary point on each line to another arbitrary point without worrying about breaking down each line into individual words (or characters??? - what about potential for notable punctuation?).

Answer (score 0):

@saritonin

After reading your comment I revisited the sources table again (`scrAuthori`). Considering the contents table (`authoriContents`) I realized that `scrAuthori`should only contain semantic units of which content destined to be translated or commentated will be composed. As you suggested (punctation) I'am now inclined to opt for sentences.

Actually my solution looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQDhM.png)

The display of the sources has to be faithful to the published version of the books (line by line, page by page, etc.) so I have find some mapping from sentences to the structure of the published book in question (e.g. Bekker numbers for Aristotle).

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather decompose this task in two parts:

1. Define addressing approach. E.g. it could be pointing starting and end symbol of quote, or something else. Anyway, for customer it could be represented in different interfaces (select paragraph or chapter and so on), but it should be exact addressing method.
2. Store in table: author_id, book_id, quote_begin, quote_end, quote_identifier_for_user, user_id, action_id, action_data, action_date_time. Something like that.

This should provide you with quite normal form, easy to manage and select data.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the comments I’am inclined to the following solution.

**Definitions**

*Sources* are the collected works of several authors.

*Content* of a source is constituted out of any words, sentences, paragraphs, chapters, etc. In short content is constituted out of semantical units found in a particular source, e.g Author, booktitle, page 1, line 4 to Author, booktitle, page 2, line 5.

**Relations**

Each *content* could be related to many *translations* (one to many).

Each *content* could be related to many *comments* and each *comment* to many *contents* (many to many).

**Tables**

For N authors their are N tables each of them contains the collected works of the author line by line.
Table of the collected works of Author i:

`scrAuthori`

```
PK
lineId | booktitle | page | linenumber | line
1      | aaa       | 1    | 1          | aaa
2      | aaa       | 1    | 2          | bbb
```

Table of authors:

`authors`

```
PK
authorId  | name
a1        | author1
a2        | author2
```

Table of contents:

`contents`

```
PK          FK         (scrAuthori.linenumber)
contentId | authorId | lineBegin | lineEnd
1         | a1       | 3         | 5
2         | a1       | 6         | 100
```

Table of translations:

`translation`

```
PK              FK          
translationId | contentId | translation
1             | 3         | aaa
2             | 4         | bbb
```

Table of comments:

`comment`

```
PK          FK          
commentId | comment
1         | aaa
2         | bbb
```

Associative table between contents and comments:

`contents_comments`

```
PK                  FK          FK           
content_commentId | contentId | commentId
1                 | 1         | 1
2                 | 1         | 2
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzoLv.png) is an image of the structure.

Is this an appropriate solution in sense of scalability (collected works of authors will be added from time time)  and of performance (each scrAuthori table could contain up to one million rows)?

Comment: Note: one comment could be to only one content. It is not neede IMHO to apply one comment to many contents. Otherwise it is better to add one more entity: translate_attempt, that should identify user who translates, and what he translates. May be one attempt to one book.